# ReactJS useEffect Hook - used more than once in a component?

Tags: reactjs

I've searched for an answer to this question but I can see to find what I need.  In a single component, can useEffect() be used more than once?

For Example:

```
export const MyDataForm = (props) => {
    ...    
    useEffect(()=>console.log(var1),[var1]);
    useEffect(()=>console.log(var2),[var2]);
    return (<></>);
}
```

Is this legal, recommended, not recommended?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Legal, and often useful.

Comment: So I have come to find out.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is permitted, and recommended depending upon your use case.

`useEffect()` allows your component to subscribe to changes to a specific state. The dependencies you pass in the array of the second argument are those you wish to subscribe to within the callback. It doesn't make sense to subscribe to all of them in a single `useEffect()`.

For instance, let's say you have a `user` and `invoices` state variable coming from your Redux store. You may wish to perform an action when `user` changes, but not when `invoices` does, and conversly when `invoices` changes but not `user`. If you add both of these entities to the dependency array of a single `useEffect()` hook, the callback when will be executed when *either* of the entities changes, not both of them. This can lead to unnecessary re-renders.

You should add two separate `useEffect()` hooks to achieve this, for example:

```js
useEffect(() => { 
   // Executed when user changes
}, [ user ]);

useEffect(() => { 
    // Executed when invoices changes
}, [ invoices ]);

useEffect(() => {
    // Executed when either user OR invoices changes
}, [ user, invoices ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it makes sense, there's no problem in using useEffect more than once. Especially in your case where you have different dependencies for each hook.

Comment: This does not explain *why* you need to use multiple `useEffect()` hooks.

Comment: BemM - I don't ask why I NEEDED to use multiple hooks.  I wanted to know if it could be done.

Comment: In which case, running your code would have answered your question.

Comment: Code running successfully means nothing about good practices

Answer (score 0):

Simply - yes, you can use as many useEffects as you want.

Given you have individual deps for each hook you likely should be seperating the logic.

I didn't see anything in the React docs but they do speak about using multiple useEffect and useState hooks [here][1] if that gives you a little more confidence you're doing the right thing.

Personally I've use multiple useEffect hooks both in personal projects and in a professional environment.

[1]: [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:~:text=Explanation,Form()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%201.&text=Use%20an%20effect%20for%20persisting,%3B%20%7D](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:%7E:text=Explanation,Form()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%201.&text=Use%20an%20effect%20for%20persisting,%3B%20%7D))%3B%20%2F%2F%203.

Comment: This does not explain *why* you need to use multiple `useEffect()` hooks.

Comment: That isn't what he asked.

Comment: I didn't need to know  why I need them.  I just wanted to know if it could be done.